# Android: checking a button is enabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am having problems testing my app. I created an espresso test which is supposed to fail, since whenever I launch my app in the emulator, I get the expected behavior. There is my test:

```
 onView(withText("wrong answer")).perform(click());
 onView(withId(R.id.nextQuestionButton)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
```

When launching the test, nothing is reported, whereas nextQuestionButton should **not** be enabled upon clicking the radioButton whose text is "wrong answer".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to what I understand, you want it to work like this:

> if `nextQuestionButton` IS enabled, then take following actions:
>
> - click on 'wrong answer',
> - check if `nextQuestionButton` changed stated to NOT enabled.

If this is so, the code should be like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.nextQuestionButton)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
onView(withText("wrong answer")).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.nextQuestionButton)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
```

Espresso allows you to use Hamcrest matchers in tests.

[Hamcrest 1.3 Quick Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf).

Please check also this (if you haven't done that already):

[Espresso  2.1. Espresso Cheat Sheet Master](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet) [updated]

According to this fragment of your post:

> When launching the test, nothing is reported, whereas `nextQuestionButton` should not be enabled upon clicking the `radioButton` whose text is "wrong answer".

It means that you hadn't set disabled your next question button, so Espresso passes this test.

Comment: I cant use 'matches(isEnabled())' it says that we require viewAssertion but found boolean!!!!!! i using kotlin

Comment: Cheat Sheet Site not Found! Please update your answer

Comment: @dudi sorry for inconvenience. Link updated. Anything more you need? :-)

Comment: matches(not(isEnabled())) is not working for me. I get these 2 errors: Type mismatch: inferred type is Validator but Matcher<in View!>! was expected and Type mismatch: inferred type is Matcher<View!>! but Validator was expected. How to fix this?

Comment: You can also use `matches(isNotEnabled())`